Is it safe to delete or move a file immediately after copying it? [Windows especially]
I understand that sometimes when copying a file the system will 'cache' the process of copying, or will 'delay' the process: i.e., it takes a little longer for the copying-process to actually complete than a 'process completed' UI-notification would lead you to believe. This is why it's not good to straight-up remove External Hard-Drives immediately after copying to them, but to wait just a little bit before doing so.
So, now say I copy a file, either to another folder inside the same Drive, or to a different Drive altogether. Now, I immediately move that source-file to another folder, or else delete it (move it to the bin); would doing so endanger either the source-file or its newly-made copy, with regards to file-corruption? Or rather, does the computer have a system in-place to guard against this eventuality, by automatically preventing any actual moving or deleting of the source-file before the copying has fully completed?

One of the jobs of a good OS is to provide reliable access to files. Down deep there is hardware, then drivers, abstract block devices, filesystems with their guts, finally the layer where you work with files (I may be overlooking some layers). Caching, optimizations or whatever non-erroneous operation in a deeper layer may speed up or slow down a shallower layer, but it shall not affect it in any other way; especially it shall not cause data corruption. Ejecting prematurely is an error in the hardware layer. Is Windows good in this matter? It should be, otherwise there would be a major bug.

while the first process has been completed. Subsequent processes will not affect it. (Just Idea)

Ejecting prematurely is an error in the hardware layer. No it's not, because the whole concept of ejecting early an operating system or file system thing. And exactly for the reason you mentioned already: There might be caches above the hardware and operating systems and file systems need to know how to deal with hardware regarding these caches, what assumptions about the availability of the hatrdware they can make to optimize those caches. Things are different regarding e.g. an USB stick, which users might want to eject at any time vs. internal disks, where this is not as easy possible.

@ThorstenSchöning A piece of hardware disappearing (and thus becoming inoperable) when other entities (including software) still need it is an error with the hardware, regardless if caused by a user plugging out a USB or by an actual hardware failure. This is what I meant.

Plugging out an USB stick by a user at any time is considered a valid use-case. That's why operating systems have special strategies to deal with devices like these, e.g. not caching writes at all. Windows even has UIs with settings how to deal with those devices.

If you create a file in one folder, then move the file to another folder, the file location in the disk won’t change.

(In Windows) I am guessing you'll keep seeing a "this file is open in [application name here]" warning when you try to move/delete the file until the previous copy is complete.

@Ramhound Thanks.

@Salman A Thanks for that.


So, now say I copy a file, either to another folder inside the same Drive, or to a different Drive altogether.

That's a somewaht important distinction, because different drives means different file systems most likely with different storage semantics, caching behaviour etc. So let's keep things easier and stay within the same file system.

Or rather, does the computer have a system in-place to guard against this eventuality, by automatically preventing any actual moving or deleting of the source-file before the copying has fully completed?

As your focus is Windows, the answer is somewhat yes. Windows implements an approach where applications doing something with files exclusively lock these files by default, so that no other application can access it. The first application doing something with a file needs to decide what other applications are allowed to do, read, write, delete etc. Without that explicit decision, other apps can't do anything, including moving a file during e.g. a copy process. Remember that the copy process is one app, trying to move the file at the same time another one etc. For details, have a look at CreateFileW and it's argument dwShareMode.
So, while there is a safety net available somewhat, that's most likely not needed: File system caching is handled (mostly) transparently by operating and file systems anyway. The overall goal is that users and apps don't need to deal with the details, which includes things like copying and knowing when the data is really copied for further operation. Apps can be interested in such details and e.g. might use flushing commands, which tell the operating or file system that they write the cache to data for some file right now and the calling app waits until that finished. But in most cases that is not necessary.
This includes moving after copying: If the file system cache only is involved and not e.g. the file is still locked by the copy process itself, e.g. Windows Explorer, you are free to move the file even if not all data is written to the disk yet. That is because most file systems don't directly associate actual file data with their file names or paths, but handle both independently. So data is stored at some place, at a different one a file name is stored referencing its parent path and referencing the data as well. So when the file name itself is changed or moved to some other directory, it simply keeps the reference(s) to the actual data and operating system and file system can at the same time continue to flush their caches to the place they already associated with the file name.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode
Modern file systems don't even need to care or know beforehand how much data needs to be written, they are just allocating blocks of data somewhere following certain rules and associate each allocated block with the fille name object already existing.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extent_(file_systems)

Thanks for all that detail. So I guess the same probably applies when copying to an External Hard-Drive using the same file-system as the source-disk (NTFS).

Basically yes, only caching strategies applied by default might be a little different, depending on the config for the external drive. Most likely caches are smaller, data is more frequently written to disk etc. But the locking stuff, how names vs. data are organized, that there are fully transparent cahces at all etc. is the same.


would doing so endanger either the source-file or its newly-made copy, with regards to file-corruption? Or rather, does the computer have a system in-place to guard against this eventuality, by automatically preventing any actual moving or deleting of the source-file before the copying has fully completed?

Neither of the above. The file copy process does not rely on the original at this point; it has already read all of the original file and "written" all of the data into the new file, so the 'process completed' UI notification is kind of telling you the truth.
What's actually being cached (buffered) is only those write operations – there is a completely separate caching layer that has nothing to do with copying, but rather with writing to disk in general. Any file write, whether it's copying from one file to another or just saving a document, is first buffered in memory by the OS and only later flushed to the physical storage. (That is, the data is already "in" the file as far as programs see it, just not in the file on disk yet.)

There is a small difference between moving within the same file-system
(partition) or between differing file-systems.
For moving within the same file-system : The file's data on the disk
is entirely separate from its metadata inside the file-table.
The metadata includes a pointer to the data, but is independent of it,
in the sense that the file-entry can be moved to another folder
without moving the data.
In your case, what might happen is that the file's data has not yet
terminated to be moved and is still within the cache, while the
file-entry is moved elsewhere within the the same file-system.
No problem is encountered, and the file's data will continue to be
flushed from the cache, while the file is already located within
its new folder (including when this is the Recycle Bin).
For moving within different file-systems :
Windows will seek to copy the file's data to the new disk, then create
and entry in the new file-table, and finally delete the file on the
source disk.
While copying the data, each source block in its turn will be read
and copied. The source data may be read from the memory cache, if it was
not yet written to its place in the source disk, then copied to the
new disk. It's quite possible, for example, that the same data will
be found duplicated twice in the cache, where each copy is destined
to be written to a different disk.
When the copy operation is finished for Windows, even if not all the
blocks were written out to both disks, the source file will be deleted.
This will invalidate all its blocks in the memory cache, so that
unwritten blocks to the source file are simply cancelled.
In this case, it may be happen that deleting or moving a file
immediately after will in the end be more efficient on the disk
than waiting for the write to terminate before doing the operation.
For delete immediately after copy :
As described above, this will cancel all unwritten blocks that are still
present in the memory cache, so such blocks will never be written to
the disk.

Thanks. So it sounds like there's nothing to worry about, even in the case of copying to another disk.
